# Disable debugging XHR requests on all browser inspect tools for my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

Is there any way to disable website users to see what my web application is sending and receiving from server through ajax requests.

Is there any way i could do this for my website through coding?

The XHR, Ajax call, response shouldn't be visible on any browser inspect tools.Only I can choose to enable it only if required.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't disable debugging tools with the code that is being debugged.

There is no way to hide what you are asking the user's browser from the user. It is *their* browser so *they* get to know what it is doing.